# apache poi XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFworkbook is throwing outofMemoryError:javaheapspace

Tags: java, excel, apache, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have excelsheet to get testdata. size of excelsheet is 1120 kb and i have only 90 rows filled with data. when i am trying to create workbook object it is throwing

**"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"**

at below line of code

```
FileInputStream file =new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    try(XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file))
        {
    //code to get data from excel sheet 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i tried using poi-excelant jar also and putting workbook in try with resources (Auto-closeable) block but whenever execution goes to this line. it is throwing error message.
i read somewhere that we can use system..gc(); but if object is not created at first place how gc will work.

refered this link : [Apache POI XSSFWorkbook memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316674/apache-poi-xssfworkbook-memory-leak)

Please help in resolving this error message.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Even used file instead of fileinputstream still getting memoryleak error

Comment: can you try `new XSSFWorkbook(new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream()))`?

Comment: Did you increase the heap space with `-Xms` and `-Xmx`?

Comment: @JellyRaptor Hi Jelly, i tried with inputstream also. it didnt work. earlier it was working on my system. i dnt know what happened suddenly that it stopped working.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hi Jim, i cannot change in eclipse.ini file as i dnt have rights to do so. is there any other way we can increase the heap size ?